# Silverlight 4 HtmlPage.Document.Cookies is always empty

Tags: silverlight, wcf, session, silverlight-4.0

I'm very much new to silverlight, so please assume I've done something very daft....

I am trying to make a call from a silverlight app to a WCF service and check a value in the session. The value will have been put there by an aspx page. It's a little convoluted, but that's where we are.

My service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExportStatus
{
    [OperationContract]
    ExportState RequestExportComplete();
}

public enum ExportState
{
    Running,
    Complete
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ExportStatus : IExportStatus
{
    ExportState IExportStatus.RequestExportComplete()
    {
       // check value of session variable here.
    }
}
```

The site that hosts the silverlight app also hosts the wcf service. Its web config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="SUV_MVVM.Web.Services.ExportStatus" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="MyHttpBinding"
                          contract="SUV_MVVM.Web.Services.IExportStatus"
                          address="" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyHttpBinding" />
             </basicHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
         <behaviors>
             <serviceBehaviors>
                 <behavior name="MyBehavior">
                     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                 </behavior>
             </serviceBehaviors>
         </behaviors>
         <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
         <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I added the service reference to my silverlight app using the VS tooling acepting the defaults (apart for the namespace)

Initially I was just trying to call the service like this:

```
var proxy = new ExportStatusClient();
proxy.RequestExportCompleteCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                        {
                                            //Handle result
                                        };

proxy.RequestExportCompleteAsync();
```

But the session in the service was always empty (not null, just empty), so I tried manually setting the session Id into the request like this:

```
var proxy = new ExportStatusClient();
using (new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    //this might chnage if we alter the cookie name in the web config.
    request.Headers["ASP.NET_SessionId"] = GetCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;
    proxy.RequestExportCompleteCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                            {
                                                //Handle result
                                            };

     proxy.RequestExportCompleteAsync();
  }

  private string GetCookie(string key)
  {
      var cookies = HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');

        return (from cookie in cookies
                select cookie.Split('=')
                into keyValue 
                where keyValue.Length == 2 && keyValue[0] == key 
                select keyValue[1]).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

But what I'm finding is that the `HtmlPage.Document.Cookies` property is always empty.

So Am I just missing something really basic, or are there any other things that I need to change or test?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test from a Silverlight 4 application.

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Cookies = "KeyName1=KeyValue1;expires=" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10).ToString("R");
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Cookies = "KeyName2=KeyValue2;expires=" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60).ToString("R");

Each cookie expired as expected.

The value of System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Cookies...

Immediately after setting the cookies: "KeyName1=KeyValue1; KeyName2=KeyValue2"

30 seconds later: "KeyName2=KeyValue2"

60+ seconds later: ""